# Scaling camera in ARCore Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

This is Jake from HandMade Game. We're working on porting our VR game, [CRANGA](https://www.handmadegame.net/cranga), onto AR Core.

Our game, CRANGA, has pretty big objects (containers). In VR, we used to setup the Camera's scale to 100, 100, 100 so that the positional tracking matches the game's scale.

In the ARCore example scene, we're trying to spawn on a TrackedPlane's position a much bigger object than 'Andy' prefab.

Since the object is too large, we tried to scale up the camera, but then the TrackedPlane's position does not match with the real scene. Plus, spawned objects' positions are messed up.

Should we always keep the Camera's scale to 1, 1, 1, or is there any other way around? (Scaling down all the objects messes up the physics, so we try not to do so, unless there's no other way.)

Thanks!

Comment: what is the name of your game again?

Comment: just make the models smaller on import and keep camera at scale 1,1,1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should keep the main camera scale to 1, 1, 1. If you adjust your physics/mass/other config items accordingly, you may be able to recreate the same physics. Another option like @Everts mentioned is to make the models smaller on import/in the import settings.

Your game looks awesome :) would love to play it in AR.

Comment: We actually figured out to scale the ARCore's plane and anchor prior prior to game update. Thanks for your comment  :)

Comment: No problem! If I helped feel free to mark my note as a correct answer :)

Answer (score -1):

- you can scale via making your whole scene (Camera and new instantiated objects) have a scaled parent object.
- you can also scale via scaling each object on instantiation.

however I tried those solutions and it seems like physics get messed up especially wheel colliers are very unhappy.they keep registering friction. and vehicle moves around.

if you have found a method or a way to fix scaling with preserving physics please share.